# Sphere Collision Algorithm-Overal Velocities Keep increacing (C++, OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, geometry, collision

Im having trouble with my "Box Full of Sphere Particles" project. ive created a spheres[number_of_spheres][position,radius,velocity..] array. A bounding box (sides parallel to orthonormal axis). 
Spheres that  collide with the box have their velocity reversed on the dimention of the collision. that works ok.
For the sphere-to-sphere collision its pretty simple, i detect the collision by comparing distance to sum of radii. Now im trying to make them simply exchange velocities on the axis of collision. But the simulation runs fine for a while then the speeds keep increasing till its out of control.

```
bool CollisionDetect(int i, int j)
{
    if(i==j)
    {
        return false;
    }

    float xx = (spheres[i][0]-spheres[j][0])*(spheres[i][0]-spheres[j][0]);
    float yy = (spheres[i][1]-spheres[j][1])*(spheres[i][1]-spheres[j][1]);
    float zz = (spheres[i][2]-spheres[j][2])*(spheres[i][2]-spheres[j][2]);

    if( (xx + yy + zz) <= (spheres[i][3] + spheres[j][3])*(spheres[i][3] + spheres[j][3]) ) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

void CollisionSolve(int i, int j)
{
    float m1,m2,m21;

    Vec3 vel1,vel2,pos1,pos2;   //spheres info

    Vec3 nv1n,nv1b,nv1t; 
    Vec3 nv2n,nv2b,nv2t;

    Vec3 N,T,B,X,Y,Z;           //collision plane and world orthonormal basis

    X.x=1;
    X.y=0;
    X.z=0;
    Y.x=0;
    Y.y=1;
    Y.z=0;
    Z.x=0;
    Z.y=0;
    Z.z=1;

    pos1.x = spheres[i][0];
    pos2.x = spheres[j][0];
    pos1.y = spheres[i][1];
    pos2.y = spheres[j][1];
    pos1.z = spheres[i][2];
    pos2.z = spheres[j][2];
    vel1.x = spheres[i][4];
    vel2.x = spheres[j][4];
    vel1.y = spheres[i][5];
    vel2.y = spheres[j][5];
    vel1.z = spheres[i][6];
    vel2.z = spheres[j][6];

    m1 =  spheres[i][8];
    m2 =  spheres[j][8];                        //mass (for later)

    N = minus(pos2,pos1);                       //get N vector (connecting centers of spheres)
    N = Normalize(N);

    T=X;

    B = crossProduct(N,T);                      //find first perpendicular axis to N 

    if (B.x==0 && B.y==0 && B.z==0)             //then vector parallel to X axis - 
    {
        T=Y;                                    //try Y axis
        B = crossProduct(N,T);  
    }

    T = crossProduct(N,B);                      //find second perpendicular axis to N   
    T = Normalize(T);
    B = Normalize(B);


    if (simplespherecollision)
    {
        nv1n = projectUonV (vel1 , N);
        nv2n = projectUonV (vel2 , N);
        vel1 = minus (vel1,nv1n);
        vel2 = minus (vel2,nv2n);
        vel1 = plus (vel1,nv2n);
        vel2 = plus (vel2,nv1n);
                    //simply switch speed (for test)
    }

    /*/---THIS IS COMMENTED OUT (FIRST METHOD USED - DIDNT WORK)--------------------------------------------
    nv1n = projectUonV (vel1 , N);
    nv2n = projectUonV (vel2 , N);
    nv1t = projectUonV (vel1 , T);
    nv2t = projectUonV (vel2 , T);
    nv1b = projectUonV (vel1 , B);
    nv2b = projectUonV (vel2 , B);              //project velocities on new orthonormal basis

    vel1 = plus(nv1t , plus(nv1b , nv2n));      //project velocities back to world basis 
    vel2 = plus(nv2t , plus( nv2b , nv1n));     //by adding the sub vectors with swiched Xn
    /*/----------------------------------------------------------------------

    spheres[i][4] = vel1.x;
    spheres[i][5] = vel1.y;
    spheres[i][6] = vel1.z;
    spheres[j][4] = vel2.x;
    spheres[j][5] = vel2.y;
    spheres[j][6] = vel2.z;                     //reasign velocities to spheres

}
}
```

And this is the Vec3 struct (just in case)

```
struct Vec3
{
   float x, y, z;
};

Vec3 crossProduct(const Vec3& v1, const Vec3& v2)
{
    Vec3 r;
    r.x = (v1.y*v2.z) - (v1.z*v2.y);
    r.y = (v1.z*v2.x) - (v1.x*v2.z);
    r.z = (v1.x*v2.y) - (v1.y*v2.x);
    return r;
}

Vec3 minus(const Vec3& v1, const Vec3& v2) 
{
    Vec3 r;
    r.x = v1.x - v2.x;
    r.y = v1.y - v2.y;
    r.z = v1.z - v2.z;
    return r;
}

Vec3 plus(const Vec3& v1, const Vec3& v2) 
{
    Vec3 r;
    r.x = v1.x + v2.x;
    r.y = v1.y + v2.y;
    r.z = v1.z + v2.z;
    return r;
}

double dotProduct(const Vec3& v1, const Vec3& v2) 
{
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y + v1.z * v2.z;
}

Vec3 scale(const Vec3& v, double a) 
{
    Vec3 r;
    r.x = v.x * a;
    r.y = v.y * a;
    r.z = v.z * a;
    return r;
}

Vec3 projectUonV(const Vec3& u, const Vec3& v) 
{
    Vec3 r;
    r = scale(v,dotProduct(u,v));
    return r;
}

int distanceSquared(const Vec3& v1, const Vec3& v2) 
{
    Vec3 delta = minus(v2, v1);
    return dotProduct(delta, delta);
}

Vec3 Normalize (const Vec3& v)
{
    Vec3 r;
    r=v;
    int mag = sqrt(dotProduct(v,v));
    r.x = v.x/mag;
    r.y = v.y/mag;
    r.z = v.z/mag;
    return r;
}
```

And this is my Render function witch draws the spheres and the bounding box and calls the other functions

```
void Render()
{    
  //CLEARS FRAME BUFFER ie COLOR BUFFER& DEPTH BUFFER (1.0)
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  // Clean up the colour of the window
                                                       // and the depth buffer
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
  glLoadIdentity();

  glTranslatef(-MAX_X/2,-MAX_Y/2,-MAX_Z*4);
  glTranslatef (dx,0,dz);

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //-----------------------------BOUNDING BOX----------------------------------------------------
    glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(MAX_X/2,MAX_Y/2,MAX_Z/2);
            glColor4f(0.9,0.6,0.8,0.3);
            glScalef(MAX_X,MAX_Y,MAX_Z);
            glutSolidCube(1);
            glutWireCube(1);
    glPopMatrix();
  //-----------------------------WALL COLLISION DETECTION-----ALWAYS ON--------------------------------
    for (int i = 0; i<PART_NUM; i++)
    {

        if(spheres[i][0] > (MAX_X - spheres[i][3]) && spheres[i][4] > 0)
        {
            spheres[i][4] = spheres[i][4]*-1;
            wallcollcount++;
        }
        if(spheres[i][1] > (MAX_Y - spheres[i][3]) && spheres[i][5] > 0)
        {
            spheres[i][5] = spheres[i][5]*-1;
            wallcollcount++;
        }
        if(spheres[i][2] > (MAX_Z - spheres[i][3]) && spheres[i][6] > 0)
        {
            spheres[i][6] = spheres[i][6]*-1;
            wallcollcount++;
        }
        if(spheres[i][0] < spheres[i][3] && spheres[i][4] < 0)
        {
            spheres[i][4] = spheres[i][4]*-1;
            wallcollcount++;
        }
        if(spheres[i][1] < spheres[i][3] && spheres[i][5] < 0)
        {
            spheres[i][5] = spheres[i][5]*-1;
            wallcollcount++;
        }
        if(spheres[i][2] < spheres[i][3] && spheres[i][6] < 0)
        {
            spheres[i][6] = spheres[i][6]*-1;
            wallcollcount++;
        }
//--------------------------------------Sphere ColDit -------------------------
        if (spherecollision || simplespherecollision)
        {
            for(int j=i+1; j<PART_NUM; j++)
            {
                if(CollisionDetect(i,j))
                {
                    spherecollcount++;
                    CollisionSolve(i,j);
                }
            }
        }
//-----------------------------------------------DRAW--------------------------------
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(spheres[i][0],spheres[i][1],spheres[i][2]);
            glColor3f( (float) (i+1)/(PART_NUM)   , 1-(float)(i+1)/(PART_NUM)  ,  0.5);
            glutSolidSphere(spheres[i][3], 18,18);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

  glutSwapBuffers();             // All drawing commands applied to the 
                                 // hidden buffer, so now, bring forward
                                 // the hidden buffer and hide the visible one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things conserved in a collision:

- momentum

and

- energy

So far your calculations just consider the momentum (a simply speed swap assumes a so called central collision and identical masses of the spheres). If computers were infinitely precise this would work out perfectly. But computers have only limited precisions and so roundoff errors will creep in.

The simple solution for that problem is to correct the momentum part (which is mass · velocity) for the deviation in energy (1/2 mass · velocity²). This works because energy depends by the square of the velocity so small deviations on the speeds involved will create large energy deviations which you can use for correcting the calculation.

I.e. you calculate the total energy before the collision and then after the collision. Then you take the ratio sqrt(E_before / E_after) and scale the speeds after the calculation with that.

If you want to be really accurate you could do relativistic momentum and energy transfer ;)

Comment: thanx for the reply!!! :D  i will try scaling the speed as you suggest. but i dont really know what is relativistic momentum.